# Property of 0 (smallest element) in a finite lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I encountered the following statement in a non-math book (on digital systems, actually), where the author discusses lattices and Boolean algebras:

> The following properties are valid for every finite lattice:
>   $a+0=a$ and $a.0=0$

I can't see how the proof of these properties could not be valid for an infinite lattice? Could someone give any counter examples to this?

Comment: Must infinite lattices have a smallest element?

Comment: To begin with, an infinite lattice may not have a least element.

Comment: Some people (unfortunately) define lattices in a way that doesn't require the existence of a smallest element. In a finite lattice, that would follow from the other requirements, but an infinite lattice could, under such a definition, not have a $0$ element at all. In that case, the equations you're asking about wouldn't make sense. Whenever a $0$ element exists in a lattice, it satisfies these equations.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Why "unfortunately?"  That is, why exclude lattices that are not complete?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I don't want to require latices to be complete; my preferred definition is that they are **finitely** complete, i.e., every finite subset has a greatest lower bound and a least upper bound.  In particular, the empty set has these bounds, 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: Ah, I get it now.. the existence, and therefore uniqueness, of 0 and 1 is dependent on the fact that the lattice is finite

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the clarification.  So, the set of all finite subsets of an infinite set is not finitely complete (under set inclusion) because it doesn't have a greatest element.

Comment: @ArkyaChatterjee Almost right.  An infinite lattice may have 0 and 1.  Think of the powerset of an infinite set.  The empty set is 0 and the whole set is 1.  When the lattice is finite, then it *must* have a 0 and a 1.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yeah, that's what I meant, that the certainty of existence of 0 and 1 in a finite lattice hinges on its finiteness; and hence will not in general go through for an infinite lattice.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cut down on the number of unanswered questions on this site, I post this answer.

Consider the lattice $\langle\Bbb Z_-,<\rangle,$ where $\Bbb Z_-$ is the set of negative integers and $<$ is the usual order relation on this set. Readily, there is no such thing as a $0$ of this lattice.